# Subshell for Bash Script

Tags: shell-script, shell, subshell

Sub-shell commands must be execute automatically within bash scripts.

It runs automatically then executing the sub-shell within the bash but it requires human interaction I want to execute it automatically within my bash script.

My main Bash Script command lists:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
****some-commands****
askbot-setup;
```

Sub-shell executes

```
Deploying Askbot - Django Q&A forum application
Problems installing? -> please email admin@askbot.org

To CANCEL - hit Ctr-C at any time

Enter directory path (absolute or relative) to deploy
askbot. To choose current directory - enter "."
> .

Please select database engine:
1 - for postgresql, 2 - for sqlite, 3 - for mysql, 4 - oracle
type 1/2/3/4: 3

Please enter database name (required)
> askbotdb

Please enter database user (required)
> askbotuser

Please enter database password (required)
> askbotpasswords

Copying files:
* __init__.py
* manage.py
* urls.py
* django.wsgi
Creating settings file
settings file created
```

I want to automate given commands in myshell script so that it can run without human interaction.

```
.
3
askbotdb
askbotuser
askbotpasswords
```

Then what is command for my sub shell for above commands after `askbot-setup` commands for Bash script.

Comment: Have you tried using redirects, be it pipes or a `<<<` string redirect (which could be defined in a variable, e.g. `var=".\n3\naskbotdb\naskbotuser\naskbotpasswords"; askbot-setup <<< $var`)?

Comment: please tell me procedure

Comment: @Gopal this doesn't match what you wrote in your question

Comment: @roaima sorry please tell me solution how to run automatically those commands on by one in sub-shell

Comment: The first comment shows you how to do it. But the information you then provided doesn't match what you first wrote. Right now it's impossible to help you because you're giving us inconsistent information.

Comment: @Roaima Sorry for incorrect tags.I have referred the `askbot-setup` above and commands are below. you can check above. please help me to automate those commands in bash scripts.

Comment: What version of askbot are you using? according to the [askbot initial configuration](http://askbot.org/doc/initial-configuration.html) documentation, since 0.7.24 you should be able to set those parameters non-interactively using command-line arguments

Comment: Oh, askbot is a thing? Then would the question be better phrased as "how can I set up askbot non-interactively"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I`d look at the askbot documentation first and check if askbot-setup can get its answers from the command line or via some form of an answer file.

If all else fails you can use autoexpect(1) to create an expect(1) script to simulate your manual interaction with askbot-setup.

Just to avoid confusion of terms - "subshell" typically refers to a set of commands inside a shell script that get executed in a separate process space because of being surrounded by brackets. The kind of software you are referring to here is better described as an interactive installation script.

Comment: Sorry for incorrect tags.I have referred the `askbot-setup` above and commands are below. you can check above. please help me to automate those commands in bash scripts.